# How to insert date and retrieve records based on that entered date

Tags: database, vb.net, sql-server-ce

I am a PHP-MySql Guy & new to the **vb.net & SQL Server CE.**
how to handle records based on dates ?

Consider any table(**tbl_demo**) with with some columns having 1 column to store today's date.

```
 For example (table structure)-     Id     Name       today
                                    --     -----      -----
                                    int    nvarchar   datetime
```

If i have following data in a table -

```
 Id     Name       today
 --     -----      -----
 1      vikram     11/08/2013 11:16:57 PM
```

then how do i retrieve this record by providing only **11/08/2013** to the query ?

PS-
I have facing following problem while executing the query (here is the code snippet) -

```
 Dim Ddate As Date
 Ddate = MonthCalendar1.SelectionRange.Start.ToString
```

`SQLquery = "SELECT id,today FROM tbl_demo WHERE today = '" & Ddate & "'"`

ERROR :`The data type is not valid for the boolean operation.[Data type (if known) = datetime,Data type (if known) = nvarchar]`

Answer (score 0):

Though it is not best to have functions in the fields in the where clause (performance wise) this will do the job.

```
"SELECT id,today FROM tbl_demo WHERE CONVERT(DATETIME,CONVERT(VARCHAR,today,120)) = CONVERT(DATETIME,CONVERT(VARCHAR,'" & Ddate.ToString() & "',120))"
```

An alternative would be providing the Date directly to ISO format:

```
"SELECT id,today FROM tbl_demo WHERE CONVERT(DATETIME,CONVERT(VARCHAR,today,120)) = CONVERT(DATETIME,CONVERT(VARCHAR,'" & Ddate.ToString("yyyyMMdd") & "',120))"
```

I am not sure if it is yyyyMMdd or yyMMdd for SQL CE, so better try both.

According to [this MSDN article](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174450.aspx) it should be "yyMMdd" but it could be a typo...

Answer (score 0):

While experimenting...I got this working as follows (please correct me if i wrong)

```
    Dim Ddate As Date
    Dim d, m, y
    Ddate = MonthCalendar1.SelectionRange.Start.ToString
    d = Ddate.ToString("dd")
    m = Ddate.ToString("MM")
    y = Ddate.ToString("yyyy")
```

And the Query is :

```
SQLquery = "SELECT billId,c_id,amount FROM tbl_outward WHERE (DATEPART(dd, ddate) = '" & d & "' AND DATEPART(mm, ddate) = '" & m & "' AND DATEPART(yyyy, ddate) = '" & y & "')"
```

Comment: It sounds correct. There are many ways to do it and certainly the best would be the one that utilizes the best SQL performance. So if you have a profiler available it would be nice to have a look.

Comment: While it is likely not relevant to the scenario presented here, it is a good idea to get into the habit of using parameterized queries. They help to prevent SQL injection, aid performance on most databases, and can simplify code because you can use strongly typed variables.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a complete example using a Data Reader. This is appropriate if you are going to process one row at a time. If you need to hold all the rows in memory or perform further operations you may want to use ExecuteDataSet to get the values.

This example prints the row values to the command line.

```
Dim recordDate as DateTime = new DateTime(2013,8,11)
Using connection As SqlCeConnection = New SqlCeConnection("Data Source=Database.sdf;Persist Security Info=False;")

    connection.Open()

    Using command As SqlCeCommand = connection.CreateCommand()
        command.CommandText = "Select id, name, today from demo where today = @date"
        Dim dateParameter As SqlCeParameter
        dateParameter = New SqlCeParameter("@date", DbType.DateTime)
        dateParameter.Value = recordDate
        command.Parameters.Add(dateParameter)

        Using reader As SqlCeDataReader = command.ExecuteReader()
            Do While reader.Read()
                Dim id As Integer = reader.GetInt32(0)
                Dim name As String = reader.GetString(1)
                Dim today As DateTime = reader.GetDateTime(2)
                Console.WriteLine("{0,-4} {1,-10} {2,-10}", id, name, today)
            Loop

        End Using

    End Using
End Using
```

A few important things to note:

- The Using statements automatically clear up unused resources when you are finished with them
- The sql statement used is parameterised, which allows you to pass in a strongly typed value rather than a string.

The first argument to Console.WriteLine is a string format. {0, -4} is a placeholder that will be filled by the next argument. -4 say that the value should be displayed left aligned in a column 4 characters wide. For more information, see the [String.Format](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.format.aspx) method documentation on MSDN.

Comment: but will you please explain (for the sake of my knowledge)"{0,-4} {1,-10} {2,-10}" this thing in the code...what was that ?